# Constructing a planar graph given $n$ vertices, with a neighbour constraint for every vertex

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

I have a set of data that I would be mapped very well to the panes of a planar graph. For this to work, each vertex must have a maximum total amount of 3 neighbours. The reason for this constraint is beecause the data I am interested in mapping will contain a relation between data entries if their regions share an edge & 2 vertices, so if there is a vertex with more than 3 neighbours, it may share a vertex with another region, but not an edge.

Just constructing a lattice where each vertex has 3 nodes is not difficult, but what if I want an additional constraint: each region in the lattice must have the same amount of edges. I tried constructing a planar graph this way, and could only get 5 regions:

[image]

Which isn't really a proof that such a lattice cannot exist.

My question is, is there a *minimal* $k \in \mathbb{N}$ where given $n > k$ vertices, it is possible to construct a graph where each region has $k$ edges, and each vertex has at most 3 neighbours?

Comment: Do you consider the outer face to be a region?  Do you want exactly 3 neighbours for each vertex, or at most 3?  What about the connectedness?

Comment: Yes, the outer face would have to be a region (even though in my example, I didn't say it is. It wouldn't matter either way .) Each vertex must have at most 3 neighbours. If by connectedness you mean if the vertecies are all linked, then yes.

Comment: Well, the outer face *does* matter a lot. If it's not important how many edges the outer face has, then I can give you plenty of examples. Otherwise, the number of possible graphs will be severely restricted. If you're certain about your choice, I'll post an answer.
By connectedness I meant 2- or 3-connectedness, meaning there is no cut-vertex, etc.

Comment: @Steven In that case, it would be lovely if the outer face has the same edges as the rest, if such a graph even exists.  The connectedness of each vertex musn't exceed 3, but a cut-vertex may exist.